# Print Double as Int - if not a Double value

Tags: xcode, swift, int, double

I want my Double to display as an Int,  if the value is an integer - otherwise as a Double.

Example;

```
var Value = Double()
```

.

```
Value = 25.0 / 10.0
```

Now I want `Value` to display `2.5` (when inserted to label)

.

`Value = 20.0 / 10.0`

Now I want `Value` to display `2` - and NOT `2.0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One classic way is to establish a value for epsilon which represents your tolerance for considering a value close enough to an `Int`:

```
// How close is close enough to be considered an Int?
let kEPSILON = 0.0001

var val = 1.9999
var str: String

if abs(val - round(val)) < kEPSILON {
    str = String(Int(round(val)))
} else {
    str = String(val)
}

print(str)  // "2"
```

Comment: I will only encounter two different situations: Either `val` is an Int or `val = 2.5` -- Should I use `kEPSILON = 0.1` then? :-)

Comment: In your case `0.1` would work.  There's no harm in using `0.0001` either.

Comment: @RappeStegarn if the only case where val is not an int is if it's 2.5, then you can just check if it's 2.5, and if not, cast it as an int. i.e. Int(val)

Answer (score 4):

One approach is to obtain the fractional part using `%` operator, and check if it is zero:

```
let stringVal = (Value % 1 == 0)
?  String(format: "%.0f", Value)
:  String(Value)
```

Answer (score 2):

To display numbers as text, use `NSNumberFormatter()`. You can  set its `minimumFractionDigits`
property to zero:

```
let fmt = NSNumberFormatter()
fmt.minimumIntegerDigits = 1
fmt.maximumFractionDigits = 4
fmt.minimumFractionDigits = 0

print(fmt.stringFromNumber(25.0 / 10.0)!)  // 2,5
print(fmt.stringFromNumber(20.0 / 10.0)!)  // 2
print(fmt.stringFromNumber(2.0 / 7.0)!)    // 0,2857
```

If you want a decimal *period*, independent of the user's locale, 
then add

```
fmt.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
```

**Swift 3:**

```
let fmt = NumberFormatter()
// Optional:
fmt.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")

fmt.minimumIntegerDigits = 1
fmt.maximumFractionDigits = 4
fmt.minimumFractionDigits = 0

print(fmt.string(from: 25.0 / 10.0 as NSNumber)!)  // 2,5
print(fmt.string(from: 20.0 / 10.0 as NSNumber)!)  // 2
print(fmt.string(from: 2.0 / 7.0 as NSNumber)!)    // 0,2857
```

Answer (score 2):

I like dasblinkenlight's and vacawama's answers, but also want to contribute another one: Using NSNumberFormatter

```
let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .DecimalStyle
formatter.alwaysShowsDecimalSeparator = false

let string0 = formatter.stringFromNumber(25.0/10.0)!
let string1 = formatter.stringFromNumber(20.0/10.0)!

print(string0)
print(string1)
```

result:

```
2.5
2
```

The most important advantage: It is localized. On german devices it will show 2,5 instead of 2.5, just as it would be expected by a german speaking user.

Answer (score 0):

Working on a calculator on Swift 4, I treated the number variables as **String** so I could display them on screen and converted them to **Double** for the calculations, then convert them back to **String** to display the result. When the result was an **Int** I didn't want the .0 to be displayed as well so I worked this out and it was pretty simple

```
    if result.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 1) == 0{
    screenLabel.text = String(Int(result))
    }
    else{
    screenLabel.text = String(result)
    }
```

so *result* is the variable in **Double** format, if divided by 1 it gives us 0 (perfect division means its an **Int**), I convert it in **Int**.