# Display Double as Int if it is a whole number in Swift

Tags: swift

I am trying to write a method that will check to see if the Double ends in .0 vs anything else. So for example checking if it is 2.0 vs 2.12345.

If it is 2.0 then I want it to display just 2, but if it is 2.12345 then show 2.12345.

I had the idea of writing a func that took the Double as a parameter and returned an Int, but if the input turns out to be .12345 it cannot return it.

So I was wondering if the way I was thinking would work with tweaking or if there is a much similar means.

I was thinking maybe the return type could somehow be both Int & Double, but I do not know how that would work.

This is what I have so far

```
  private func checkIfWholeNumber(displayedDouble: Double) -> Int {
    if displayedDouble.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 1) == 0 {
      return Int(displayedDouble)
    } else {
      return //
    }
  }
```

Comment: You probably want to display this number on some label, right?

Comment: You should be using a `NumberFormatter`. Don't check if the number is integer or not.

Comment: @NiravD yes I am

Comment: @RubberDucky4444 Then you can make return type `String` instead of `Int` and `Double`

Comment: @RubberDucky4444 Then there are two better ways. If you want to display `1`, `1.2` and `1.23` then just set the maximum number of fractional digits. If you want to display `1`,  `1.20`, `1.23` then another possible solution is to check whether the string ends with regular expression `[.,]00` and truncate the last 3 characters if yes.
I am sure this is a duplicate question by the way but I cannot find it.

Comment: Just set the `minimumFractionDigits` of the formatter to zero, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/36649440/1187415 for an example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print Double as Int - if not a Double value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36648670/print-double-as-int-if-not-a-double-value)

Comment: All of these solutions return a String, whereas I want it to be a Double or Int, I do the conversion from Double to String elsewhere in my app

Comment: @RubberDucky4444: Checking for being an exact integer is problematic. For example `let x = 0.1 + 0.2 - 0.3` does not evaluate to zero but to a very small number – try `print(x.debugDescription)` .  Therefore the decision if and how many decimal digits to display is best done when formatting the floating point value as a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert Double into Number and then to String if u want to show it on label

```
let i = 1.0
let j = 1.2345

// Value in String

let a = NSNumber(value: j).stringValue  // "1.2345"
let b = NSNumber(value: i).stringValue  // "1" 

// Value in Double

let c = NSNumber(value: i).doubleValue  // 1.0
let d = NSNumber(value: j).doubleValue  // 1.2345
```

Comment: or just `"\(1.2345)"`

Comment: `let c = NSNumber(value: i).doubleValue` doesn't return `1`. Instead it returns `1.0`. Only conversion to `NSNumber` should be the answer.

Answer (score 1):

simply use `rounded` function.

```
func check(val:Double)->Int?{
    let rounded = val.rounded()
    return rounded == val ? Int(rounded) : nil
}
```

Comment: Note that `check(val: 0.1 + 0.2 - 0.3)` returns `nil` – which may be desired or not.

Comment: Thats because of the precision of doubles. The result of your input can be `0.0000...00001` or to be exact ('on my system') `5.55111512312578e-17`

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4+**

```
let i = 2.0
let j = 2.12345

let nf = NumberFormatter()
nf.maximumFractionDigits = 6

let a = nf.string(for: i) ?? "" // 2
let b = nf.string(for: j) ?? "" // 2.12345
```

For another option, this example uses NumberFormatter(). I just subjectively set the max digits to 6.